# Was a friend request issued, or accepted?

Tags: facebook

My friend says that she received a request from one of our classmates but I think she is lying. I think that she sent it.

How might I determine who *sent* the request to the other?

Comment: You can't see a friend request unless you are one of the people involved (sender or receiver).

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense.  A friend request is from one person to another, so by definition the person who sent the request is the person who is requesting to be a friend.

Comment: @pnuts Ah.  (I didn't upvote or downvote, by the way.)  The person who was on the receiving end of the friend request would have an entry in their new activity dropdown, the person who sent the request wouldn't.

Comment: @pnuts 1 rep -> down, down, votes counted but rep not reduced cause at 1, upvote, 1-> 6, downvote.,6 -> 4

Answer (score 1):

If the friend request was accepted on either side, it will not be possible to tell which person sent the request without going into his/her account.

If the friend request has not been accepted yet, the person who has the other as a follower at https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/followers is the receiver of the friend request.